# Filter retults of a Svelte Promise

Tags: svelte-3

In making my first app with **Svelte** I loved it except for the following which came up when filtering the results of a promise from a text input called **search**.

Filtering **products** before the promise resolves fails  as **products** is type **function**.

I had to include a **type** check before continuing...

```
typeof products === "object" && ...
```

```
{#await promise then products}
    <div class="flex justify-center flex-wrap">
        {#each typeof products === "object" && 
            products.filter((s) => 
                s.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
            ) as product
        }
            <Product
                {product}
                {handleSelectProduct}
                selected={selectedProducts.includes(product)}
            />
        {/each}
    </div>
{/await}
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: The filtering should always happen after the promise resolves. Could you add your promise code to the question, please?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to validate `typeof products === "object"`. But it's good practice to keep the logic (like filters) out of the template and keep the template "lean".

see example below (can run in `https://svelte.dev/repl/`)

```html
<script>
  let search = "c";
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve([{ name: "abc" },{ name: "bcd" },{ name: "cde" },{ name: "def" }]);
  });

  $: filtered = promise.then((r) =>
    r.filter((s) =>
      s.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
    )
  );
</script>

<input bind:value={search}>

{#await filtered then products}
  <ul>
    {#each products as product}
    <li>{product.name}</li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/await}

{#await promise then products}
  <ul>
    {#each products.filter((s) =>
      s.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())) as product
    }
    <li>{product.name}</li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/await}
```

Both blocks have the same result, so the `typeof` check is not needed (but the first one is a bit easier on the eyes).

If you are having issues that are requiring you to validate the product type, you should check the result of the promise.

Comment: Thanks!
1. your second version was my first attempt and it fails for the reason I gave. (App.svelte:159 Uncaught TypeError: ctx[15].filter is not a function)
2. in your first version your filter is filtering the return of the promise it will not filter in real time but only filter the return data?

Comment: updated answer with reactive values (https://svelte.dev/repl/5a096f5402b247b0a4f08ba532e08568?version=3.31.2)

Comment: Can you get the value of `ctx[15]`? it's not getting an array for some reason, and I think that it is unrelated to the `await` block. It may be getting a null or some other value, or be called multiple times, but I think you're looking in the wrong area. Also, both array and objects return object for `typeof`, so `Array.isArray(products)` is safer.